# Write $AS$ as a multiple of $AD$ and $CS$ as a multiple of $CE$.

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles, problem-solving

In a triangle $ABC$ the point $D$ is on $BC$ such that $\overline{BD}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \overline{BC}$ and the point  $E$ is on $AB$ such that $\overline{AE}=\frac{3}{5}\cdot \overline{AB}$.

The lines $AD$ and $CE$ intersect in $S$.

Write $AS$ as a multiple of $AD$ and $CS$ as a multiple of $CE$.

We have a triangle as follows, right?

[image]

But how can we get an information for $AS$ and $CS$ ? Could you give me a hint? Do we maybe use vector operations?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

Using vectors we have $$\vec{AS}+\vec{SD}=\vec{AD} \Rightarrow \vec{AS}=\vec{AD}-\vec{SD} \Rightarrow \vec{AS}=\vec{AD}+\vec{DS}$$ Does this help us ? How can we continue?

Comment: Do you know Ceva's theorem?

Comment: Actually it's the Menelaus theorem you have to apply here. But these two theorems go together anyway. Apply it 1) for the triangle BDA and line CSE 2) for triangle BCE and the line DSA

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint:

Applying Ceva's theorem we have:

$$\frac{AE}{EB}\cdot\frac{BD}{DC}\cdot\frac{CG}{AG}=1$$

Puting values we obtain:

$AG=3 CG$

As can be seen in figure, M is midpoint of BC(you have to prove it) and in triangle ABD; AM, DE and BC intersect in point F. Also we have:

$MD=\frac 23 BC-\frac 12 BC=\frac 16 BC$

Applying Ceva's theorem on this triangle we have:

$$\frac{AE}{EB}\cdot\frac{BM}{MD}\cdot \frac{DS}{AS}=\frac 32\cdot \frac {BC/2}{BC/6}\cdot \frac{DS}{AS}=1$$

Which gives $AS=4.5 DS$ , or $AS=\frac 9{11}AD$

Similarly you can find other ratio.

Comment: I see!! Is this also solvable using vectors? Oris Ceva's theorem the only way?

Comment: @MaryStar, If you want to use vectors you need more data  such as direction number. This constrain problem to a certain condition, where using geometric method gives solution for a general  form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. I solve the problem for $AS$ and $AD$. You can do the same for $CS$ and $CE$.

As shown in the figure below, from $A$ , $B$ and $D$ draw $AH$ , $BK$ and $DL$ perpendicular to $CE$ .
[image]
We have:
$$\frac{AH}{BK} = \frac{AE}{BE} = \frac 32$$
$$\frac{BK}{DL} = \frac{BC}{DC} = \frac 31$$
$$\therefore \frac{AH}{DL} = \frac 32 \times \frac 31 = \frac 92 $$
Now we can calculate $\frac{AS}{AD}$:
$$\frac{AS}{SD} = \frac{AH}{DL} = \frac 92 $$
$$\therefore \frac{AS}{AD} = \frac{AS}{AS+SD} = \frac{9}{9+2} = \frac{9}{11} $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using vectors.

Let position vectors of the vertices be $A,B,C$. Then
$$D=\frac{B+2C}{3} \quad ; \quad  E=\frac{2A+3B}{5}$$

Let $AS=\lambda AD$ and $CS=\mu CE$, where $\lambda, \mu$ are to be found.

Then $S$ divides $AD$ in ratio $\lambda : (1-\lambda)$ and $CE$ in ratio $\mu  : (1-\mu)$, we can write position vector of $S$ in two ways as

$$S=\lambda D+(1-\lambda)A=(1-\mu)C+\mu E$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-\lambda)A+\frac{\lambda}{3}B+\frac{2\lambda}{3}C=\frac{2\mu}{5}A+\frac{3\mu}{5}B+(1-\mu)C$$

This can be solved for $\lambda, \mu$ by equating the coefficients.